# ReRouting Http to Https in MVC 3.0 Using Rules Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have to route all the requests on my site from http to https, I was succesfull in doing that by adding another class in Global.Asax.Cs

```html
  // working part for redirecting http into https 
        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
                Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
        }
```

But before that I tried by inserting Rules into WebConfig

```html
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Which is not working, But I have seen many posts here which say that Rules is the best way to route request, I have also installed URL Rewrite on my server  . Cany any one please suggest why it wasnt working ( i am getting 500 internal server error).

Does rerouting in Global.asax affect performance when there is a huge volume of requests.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I use this rule and it works like a charm:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>             
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"  />
                <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

**without any datailed info about the error i can only guess that your web.config is malformed or you put the rule section in the wrong place or URL Rewrite Module is not installed correctly**

Comment: @JordanBelfort without any datailed info about the exception i can only guess that your web.config is malformed or you put the rule section in the wrong place

Comment: No, I kept in the same place  are you using \mvc 3.0

Comment: @JordanBelfort what error are you logging? is the url rewrite module installed correctly?

Comment: Yes it is I am getting 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @JordanBelfort could you be more specific?